# Some version of graph removal lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I found the following statement in ***'A proof of the stability of extremal graphs,
Simonovits’ stability from Szemerédi’s regularity'*** by Zoltán Füredi:

Lemma: For any $\alpha>0$ and a graph $F$, there exists an integer $n_0$ such that for any graph $G$ on  $n>n_0$ vertices, if $G$ is $F$-free, then it contains a hom$(F)$-free subgraph $H$ such that $e(H)\geq e(G)-\alpha n^2.$

It seems hard to eliminate all homomorphic image of $H$ simultaneously. If $r=\chi(H)$, it is possible to obtain a $K_r$-free subgraph as stated in Theorem 1.5 of ***'The Asymptotic Number of Graphs not Containing
a Fixed Subgraph and a Problem for Hypergraphs
Having No Exponent'***, using regularity lemma. Using the same method, we can remove a given homomorphic image but not all.

How to remove all hom$(F)$ at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: The number of graphs that are homomorphic images of $F$ depends on $F$ only (and not $n$ or $H$). So you can remove them one by one using the method you mention.